# Programming to interfaces - Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I've recently installed the Facebook C# SDK using NuGet and am wondering why the types don't have associated interfaces.

What I'd like to do is inject the types from the SDK into my application however at the moment I'm not sure if I've either missed something or the SDK just doesn't contain any interfaces other than IFacebookApplication.

How is everyone else unit testing their code whilst using this SDK? Should I be downloading and implimenting the interfaces myself rather than using the NuGet installer?

Comment: Even though I had a brief experience with it, I think Facebook C# SDK has a terrible API. Apart from interfaces, you will have a hard time finding classes for response objects, or method parameters, access tokens etc. I think writing wrapper classes is also a waste of time because it offers nearly nothing to build on. I hope there are better libraries than that.

Comment: facebook changes their response objects/types all the time.  You've been warned.  Facebook C# SDK is a light-wrapper designed to explicitly mitigate this problem; you don't want to constantly wait for the library developer to push changes every week like you do for strongly-typed libraries.

Comment: Even they change their API all the time (which I believe to be a bad thing), is strong typing too much to ask? They would break my code when they change the API anyway, so instead of maintaining their SDK they make all developers maintain their own code. Am I wrong to expect some abstraction from Facebook SDK?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları - The entire Facebook API surface would be 1000s of types. While it would be possible to create strongly typed wrappers, it would be a hell of a lot of work to maintain. The library that the Facebook C# SDK actually replaced (the Facebook Developer Toolkit) failed for exactly this reason - they attempted to build types around the Facebook API and eventually the library became unmaintainable. The biggest issue is that not only does the change break your code, but it also breaks the SDK so we would have to release a new release of the Facebook.dll every time a change it made.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları - So in conclusion, we aren't going to put strong types in the Facebook C# SDK, but feel free to start your own open source project and have at it.

Comment: @NathanTotten Out of interest, how come the decision was made to not provide interfaces for the core classes in the SDK? Simplicity seems a worthwhile goal, I wonder if that's the main reason though?

Comment: The biggest reason is that it makes change harder. If we want to add a new method or property we would have to 1) break the interface which is very bad or 2) create a new interface IFacebookClient2 which is messy. We could use abstract classes instead, but our preference is to keep the SDK as basic as possible and let developers fill in the extras if they prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't use interfaces with the Facebook C# SDK. Our goal with the SDK is to keep it as simple as possible. I would actually just suggest you implement your own repository objects that utilize the FacebookClient object rather than injecting the FacebookClient object into your objects if you want to use interfaces.

The other option is to mock the FacebookClient. We use Moq for this in our test, but any mocking library should work.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, both for taking the time to answer and for clarifying this.